# Get position of imageView on cell of a UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView with custom cell that has some labels and an Image, I need to get where the image is situated in order to place a mask on top of it, I tried with the following code but every mask gets applied on top of the first cell.
This is the code I used:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIView *darken = [[UIView alloc]init];
    darken.frame = cell.img.frame;

    darken.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.4];
    [collectionView insertSubview:darken aboveSubview:cell.img];

    return cell;
}
```

How can I get the frame position of every single image on the cells?

Comment: Have you tried `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`? Also, the superview of `cell.img` is probably `cell`, so the coordinates are wrong if you insert it as a subview of `collectionView`…

Comment: Also, this does not answer your question as such, but why aren't you placing the darkening layer inside each `cell.img` instead?

Comment: @Arkku Tried but no results, anyways I can't do that because I need to darken only some of the images not all of them

Comment: ok changing  [collectionView insertSubview:darken aboveSubview:cell.img]; to  [cell insertSubview:darken aboveSubview:cell.img]; did the trick, thanks :) The only problem is that now it creates a view everytime the method gets called, I need to figure out how to create just one view and no more

Comment: Why don't you create the darken view when you create the `img`…

Comment: and where should I create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to create just one view.

```
@define IMAGE_TAG 9999

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (![cell viewWithTag:IMAGE_TAG])
    {
          UIView *darken = [[UIView alloc]init];
          darken.frame = cell.img.frame;
          [darken setTag:IMAGE_TAG];
          darken.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.4];
          [cell insertSubview:darken aboveSubview:cell.img];
    }



    return cell;
}
```